php8.2-fpm on debian 12 stopped serving files which are hebrew name
I have just upgraded my server couple days ago (a Debian 12) and php files which have in their path hebrew characters stopped being served.
Ie If I am creating the folder /var/www/html/בדיקה and under it I am adding the file info.php it will state that the file doesn't exist.
It's a php-fpm problem and not apache due to the fact that simple info.txt file works and returns plain text.
I have also tested with a newer external version of php8.3-fpm and it seems to work there perfectly.
What I did to test it: I installed a new debian 12 server and then added php8.2-fpm, enabled the cond and tested two pathes in the server ie:
http://server-ip/test/info.php
http://server-ip/test/info.txt
http://server-ip/בדיקה/info.php
http://server-ip/בדיקה/info.txt
To verify if I am maybe doing something wrong I have also tried to use the next tutorial:
https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Debian_12&p=httpd&f=7
and the results are the same
I tried to make the page work with basic info.php and it didn't worked.

Enable debug mode for the logs, do one request and show the logs with your question. Ah, and the URL is technically speaking written wrong. Provide it URL encoded (put both versions under each other so it's more useful for your trouble shooting).
